# detect (event) attempting to scroll up/down when already at top/bottom of the page with javascript or angularJS,

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

so i want to detect scrolling to the top(or bottom) when i'm already at the top(or bottom) of the page. I've seen a couple questions with similar problems here, but the only answer was to detect mousewheel event.

but considering the fact that i want to detect it when it's triggered by any similar action (like pressing the up/down key, or mousewheel and touchpad scrolling, or pageUp/Down, or home/end ...) should I create eventlisteners for each and every one of them? does anyone know a better way of doing it??

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have for you so far.  I can detect when you hit the top or bottom regardless of how you scrolled. The issue is detecting when you are trying to keep scrolling after you reached it because the scroll event does not fire unless you actually scroll.  The only thing I can think of is to programmatically scroll the screen up slightly so that you can scroll again, but I don't recommend doing that. Other than this I don't see any other way other than creating custom events for each possible way the user can scroll.

```
$(function(){
var lastScrollBarPos = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var browserViewportHeight = $(window).height(); 
   var hmtlDocHeight = $(document).height();
   var scrollBarPos = $(window).scrollTop(); 

   if (scrollBarPos > lastScrollBarPos){
       // downscroll code
       console.log('scroll down');
       if(hmtlDocHeight == browserViewportHeight + scrollBarPos){
         console.log('reached bottom');
       }
   } else {
      // upscroll code
      console.log('scroll up');   
      if(scrollBarPos == 0){
          //we are at the top and someone is scrolling
          console.log('reached top');
      }
   }
   lastScrollBarPos = scrollBarPos;
});
});
```

Comment: thanks, actually i thought of these ways and i'm looking for a better way. also i think scrolling back isn't a good way at all... because it's practically preventing user from reaching top or bottom of the page